# Animating CCSprite not working?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a sprite like this in my init method (mySprite is declared in the .h):

```
mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image1.png"];
        [mySprite setPosition:ccp(100, 300)];
        [self addChild:mySprite z:1 tag:1];
```

Then in my other method, I try to animate it like so but it doesn't seem to animate at all, I also know that the method that this is in is getting called because I NSLogged it. Anyway here is how I try to animate mySprite:

```
CCSequence *moveSequence = [CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5 position:ccp(120, 400)],[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:4 position:ccp(100, 300)], nil];
    [mySprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:moveSequence]];
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Them questionmismabout 'Why the method isn't called'? Because the code seems pretty right

Comment: So what do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance this part of the code seems right, so perhaps you would need to show more of your overall program so that we can examine what happens between your init function and your other method being called.

A couple things out of the blue:

- make sure to call retain on your sprite so that it does not get removed summarily until you are done with it
- what is "self" exactly here, is it a cocos layer? Is the layer added to the scene properly (ie, are you seeing the sprite being displayed, even if it does not move)?
- I would also look to see if anything in the scene graph might happen between the "init" call and that second method of yours, in which you execute the animation code. Is there a StopAllActions somewhere? A removeFromParent or removeAllChildren, perhaps?

Cheers

Comment: 1st Bullet: Ok so when I use retain, how should I properly release it?
2nd Bullet: It is a CCLayer. The sprite is being displayed but just not being animated.
3rd Bullet: I only have a removeAllChildren in the dealloc method. There is no stopallactions anywhere.

Comment: I fixed it, it ended up being Box2D code interfering with the CCSprite. Upvoted and Accepted anyway! Welcome to StackOverflow! :)